# An inequality related to Catalan's constant and $\zeta(3)$

Tags: inequalities, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series

Problem :

Show that :

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}<2C-1$$

Where we can see the zeta function and the Catalan's constant .

After a bounty on Maths Stack Exchange there is no satisfying answer .

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693000/show-that-frac1-zeta32c-1

My last attempt was to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on a double integral as we have :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}-\frac{\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(xz\right)}{1-xz}dxdz=\zeta(3),\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{2}{2-x^{2}-z^{2}}-1\right)dxdz=2C-1$$

We can introduce a continuous finite function $f(x)$ on $x\in(0,1)$ and we have :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}-\frac{\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(xz\right)}{1-xz}+f(x)-f(z)dxdz=\zeta(3)$$

As we can invoke symmetry . So far I cannot find a good path .

One can show as intermediate inequality :

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}<\left(\frac{\pi^{4}}{81}-\frac{1}{19\pi^{4}}\right)^{-1}<2C-1$$

We can also consider with Cauchy-Schwarz :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(\frac{2\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}-\left(1+u\right)x^{u}\right)\left(\frac{\left(d-x^{a}+b\right)^{c}}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(d-t^{a}+b\right)^{c}dt}d\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx=0.99988\cdots,u=1/2,d=\zeta(3),c=1.2,a=0.8,b=-1/10$$

We can improve the result we have with the notation above and here $b=-0.11r=1.2$:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(\frac{2\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}-\left(1+u\right)\left(x\right)^{u}+\frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{200}+\frac{\left(\cos\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sin\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{80}\right)\left(\frac{\left(r-vx^{a}+b\right)^{c}}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(r-vt^{a}+b\right)^{c}dt}d\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx=0.99992\cdots$$

If the following improvement of Cauchy Schwarz is true we have :

$$\left(1+\left(h\left(0.9978\right)\right)^{2}\right)\left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(\frac{2\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}-\left(1+u\right)\left(x\right)^{u}+\frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{200}+\frac{\left(\cos\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sin\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{p}\right)\left(\frac{\left(r-vx^{a}+b\right)^{c}}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(r-vt^{a}+b\right)^{c}dt}d\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\right)^{2}>1$$

Where the target is the minima of $h(x)$ over $[0,1]$ define as :

$$h\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{2\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}-\frac{3}{2}\left(x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{200}+\frac{\left(\cos\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sin\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{p}\right)\left(\frac{\left(r-vx^{a}+b\right)^{c}}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(r-vt^{a}+b\right)^{c}dt}d\right),p=90$$

Why not physics comes here ? see
https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.09634

> > Question:

How to show it without a calculator so by hand ?

---

Just few remarks on the use of Cauchy-Schwarz :

If we strenghening the condition here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4701003/conjectured-improvement-of-cauchy-schwarz-for-integrals we can find a $p$ as in the statement of the question such that :

$$\left(1+\left(h\left(0.9978\right)\right)^{2}\right)\left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(\frac{2\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}-\left(1+u\right)\left(x\right)^{u}+\frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{200}+\frac{\left(\cos\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sin\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{p}\right)\left(\frac{\left(r-vx^{a}+b\right)^{c}}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(r-vt^{a}+b\right)^{c}dt}d\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\right)^{2}=1$$

Remains to show the existence .

In fact the conjecture above in the mse link is false see better https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703716/conjecture-improvement-of-buniakowsky-integral-inequality-left-int-0ig-l

Using this last conjecture we have assuming $g(0)=1$ :

$$I=\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\left(-\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{8}{\pi^{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\right)\left(x\ln\left(\tan\left(x\right)+\sec\left(x\right)\right)\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\right)^{2}-\frac{4}{7}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\ln\left(\tan\left(x\right)+\sec\left(x\right)\right)dx\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(-\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{8}{\pi^{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\right)dx=I$$

then if true :

$$\int_{0}^{-I}\left(-\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{8}{\pi^{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dt+\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\left(-\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{8}{\pi^{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\right)\left(x\ln\left(\tan\left(x\right)+\sec\left(x\right)\right)\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\right)^{2}<1$$

Unfortunetaly...

Fortunetaly using a stronger statement of the conjecture we have :

$$I=\left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(\frac{2\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}-\left(1+u\right)\left(x\right)^{u}+\frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{200}+\frac{\left(\cos\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sin\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{80}\right)\left(\frac{\left(r-vx^{a}+b\right)^{c}}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(r-vt^{a}+b\right)^{c}dt}q\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\right)^{2}-\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(\frac{\left(r-vx^{a}+b\right)^{c}}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(r-vt^{a}+b\right)^{c}dt}q\right)\right)dx\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{2\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}-\left(1+u\right)\left(x\right)^{u}+\frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{200}+\frac{\left(\cos\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sin\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{80}\right)dx$$

$$\left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(\frac{2\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}-\left(1+u\right)\left(x\right)^{u}+\frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2.01}\right)\right)}{200}+\frac{\left(\cos\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sin\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{80}\right)\left(\frac{\left(r-vx^{a}+b\right)^{c}}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(r-vt^{a}+b\right)^{c}dt}q\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\right)^{2}+2.736\frac{\left(\int_{0}^{-I}\left(\left(\frac{2\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}-\left(1+u\right)\left(x\right)^{u}+\frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2.01}\right)\right)}{200}+\frac{\left(\cos\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sin\left(x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{80}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dy\right)}{1.9546}>1$$

---

I put here my progress :

Theorem (or equivalent form of continuous Callebaut inequality):

Let $f,g$ be continuous decreasing integrable on $[0,1]$ then let $p\in[0,1]$ we have :

$$I=\left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx\int_{0}^{1}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx-\left(\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}\right)$$

Then :

$$\frac{\left(\int_{0}^{I}g\left(p\right)dy\right)}{g\left(0\right)}\leq I$$

So we have :

$$I=\left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx\int_{0}^{1}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx-\left(\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}\right),f\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{2\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}-\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}},g\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{\left(\frac{6}{5}-x^{\frac{4}{5}}+-\frac{1}{10}\right)^{\frac{6}{5}}}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{6}{5}-t^{\frac{4}{5}}+-\frac{1}{10}\right)^{\frac{6}{5}}dt}1.202056931\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$k\left(x\right)=\left(\int_{0}^{I}f\left(x\right)dy\right)+\left(\int_{0}^{1}f\left(u\right)g\left(u\right)du\right)^{2}>1,x=1/9$$

Now if we fasely assume :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx\int_{0}^{1}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx=1$$

We can use a kind of  reductio ad absurdum to show that it's not equal for $x\in(0,1]$. It needs to evaluate the integral $\left(\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}$ wich seems to be a monster so I stop here .

Perhaps someone can do better .

Last update :

Let's define :

$$r\left(x\right)=x-\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\frac{x^{5}}{6}-x^{7}\cdot\frac{17}{315}+\frac{x^{9}}{165},g\left(x\right)=\frac{r\left(x\right)}{r\left(1\right)}\cdot\frac{\pi}{4},h\left(x\right)=\arctan x,q\left(x\right)=\left(h\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right)-\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{1}{10}x^{4}\left(1-x\right)+\frac{1}{3}x^{6}\left(1-x\right)^{2}+x^{8}\left(1-x\right)^{3}\right)$$

Then we have $x\in[0,1]$:

$$ q(x)\geq 0$$

Remains to divide $q(x)$ by $x$ and integrate over the $[0,1]$.Obviously we can improve it again and again using Fourier series notably.

Let :

$$q\left(x\right)=\left(h\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right)-\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{1}{10}x^{4}\left(1-x\right)+\frac{1}{3}x^{6}\left(1-x\right)^{2}+x^{8}\left(1-x\right)^{3}+x^{10}\left(1-x\right)^{4}\right)$$

Then a graph of $q(x)$ suggest we can use Fourier series notably $10000q\left(x\right)$

Here we have used hyperbolic tangent and cheated a bit with Bernoulli's number .

For $\zeta(3)$  see the cross posted question where we have also Bernoulli's number .

If someone knows why there is Bernoulli's number feel free to comment .

Comment: @mathoverflowUser Nothing just see if someone here can find a nice proof of it .

Comment: Using prime representation there is a possible use of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4668707/an-alternative-lower-bound-for-prod-i-j-1n-frac1a-ia-j1-a-ia-j/4675582#4675582

Comment: @Stefankohl Thanks you for the edit .

Comment: We have also $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(e^{-\frac{t^{6}}{3+\sqrt{3}}}\right)dt<\zeta(3)$$

Comment: Version 13 of this question. Several of those displays are extending so far to the right that they are disappearing over the edge of the page.

Comment: We have $x\in[0,1]$ : $$h(x)=\left(x-\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\frac{1}{6}x^{5}-\frac{17}{315}x^{7}+\frac{x^{9}}{166}+\frac{1}{96}\left(x^{5}\left(1-x\right)+\frac{7}{2}x^{6}\left(1-x\right)^{2}+\frac{25}{2}x^{7}\left(1-x\right)^{3}+25\left(x^{2}\left(1-x\right)^{2}\right)^{3}\right)\right)\leq \arctan(x)$$ then a probably sufficient inequality is : $$\frac{(h(x))^2}{x}-(h(x))^2\leq \frac{\arctan^{2}\left(x\right)}{x^{2}}-\arctan^{2}\left(x\right)$$ then integrate .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One has
\begin{equation}
    C=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}
    =\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_1(k)=S_{1,c}(f_1)+S_{2,c}(f_1),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    S_{1,c}(f):=\sum_{k=0}^{c-1}f(k),\quad S_{2,c}(f):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(c+k),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    f_1(x):=\frac{1}{(4 x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(4 x+3)^2}=\frac{8 (2 x+1)}{(4 x+1)^2 (4 x+3)^2}; 
\end{equation}
note that all derivatives of $f_1$ of even orders are decreasing on $[0,\infty)$.

To evaluate $S_{2,c}(f)$, use the Euler--Maclarin formula
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k)=A_m(f)+R_m(f)
\end{equation}
for $f(x)=f_1(x+c)$, where $m$ is an integer $\ge2$,
\begin{equation}
        A_m(f):=\frac{f(0)}2-\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}\frac{B_{2j}}{(2j)!}\,f^{(2j-1)}(0),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    |R_m(f)|\le\frac{2\zeta(2)}{(2\pi)^{2m-1}}f^{(2m-2)}(0)
    =\frac{\pi^2/3}{(2\pi)^{2m-1}}f^{(2m-2)}(0);
\end{equation}
cf. e.g. formulas (2.1) and (2.4) [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00211-018-0978-y) or [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03247).

Choosing now $m=3$ and $c=3$, we get $|R_m(f_1)|<2/10^6$ and
\begin{equation}
    S_{1,c}(f_1)+A_m(f_1)>\frac{915965}{1000000},
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
    C>C_*:=\frac{915965}{1000000}-2/10^6. 
\end{equation}

Similarly, with $f_2(x):=\frac1{(x+1)^3}$ instead of $f_1(x)$, $m=3$, and $c=4$, we get
\begin{equation}
    \zeta(3)>\zeta_*(3):=\frac{1202056}{1000000} - 10^{-5}. 
\end{equation}

So,
\begin{equation}
    \zeta(3)(2C-1)>\zeta_*(3)(2C_*-1)=\frac{250003330149}{250000000000}>1.\quad\Box 
\end{equation}

---

In this setting, the derivatives of $f_1$ and $f_2$ of all orders are very simple, and the required accuracy of calculations is low (to just $5$ or $6$ digits). Otherwise, much more effective is the alternative (to Euler--Maclarin) summation formula given in the linked paper.

Answer (score 13):

Just a comment to clarify the order of brutality of a brute force computation by hand: one has, for instance
$$2C- \frac1{\zeta(3)}=16\sum_{n=0}^{\bf \infty}\frac{2n+1}{(4n+1)^2(4n+3)^2}-\prod_{n=1}^{\bf\infty}\Big(1-\frac1{p_n^3}\Big)>\\ >16\sum_{n=0}^{\bf 57 }\frac{2n+1}{(4n+1)^2(4n+3)^2}-\prod_{n=1}^{\bf 30}\Big(1-\frac1{p_n^3}\Big)>1.0000002,$$
but neither $(56,30)$ nor $(57,29)$  would do.